# Add desktop icon only if not running silently

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to only apply this task if setup is not running silently. I've already tried adding the flags attribute, but is not applicable to anything other than RUN directive.

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}";

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}";
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) with the [`WizardSilent` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardsilent).

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; ... ; Check: not WizardSilent
```